# Is there any way to check if an element has any changes on mouseover by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to detect if an element has any changes, such as the background-color changes to another or cursor changes to pointer, on mouseover by javascript.

I thought about using getComputedStyle(element, ":hover") but this is not available with :hover pseudo.

I also tried to simulate mouse over by jQuery like below, but it seems like it does not work as I expected.

```
$obj.css('cursor')
$obj.mouseover().css('cursor')
```

Is there any good way?

Comment: What's the actual purpose, what do you need this info for?

Comment: I want to make a bookmarklet to analyze other websites.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an eventlistener, such as "mouseenter" and then console log every time the mouse hovers over an element.

If you test out this code, you will see that the number of times you have hovered over the list items will appear in the console.

here is a link to "mouseover" event documentation, which I used and edited to help simplify my answer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>


  <ul id="test">
    <li>Check if item has been hovered over</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ul>


  <script>
    let test = document.getElementById("test");
    // This handler will be executed only once when the cursor moves over the unordered list
    test.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
      // highlight the mouseenter target
      console.log("purple has been hovered over")
      event.target.style.color = "purple";
      // reset the color after a short delay
      setTimeout(function() {
        event.target.style.color = "";
      }, 500);
    }, false);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi!  Nice answer. Would you mind making it a snippet? The `[<>]` button can make your code run directly in StackOverflow.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks! I was not aware code could run directly in StackOverflow, and I have now added the snippet.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not exactly what I need to do. I need to check an element has any changes without actually move the mouse on the element, only by script.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do it via jQuery like that. You probably need to get the stylesheets for the document and manually iterate through them to find matches to your selector.

```js
function getCss(cssSelector){
    var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
    var matchedRules = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++) {
        var rules = styleSheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
        for (var j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {
            if (rules[j].selectorText === cssSelector) {
                matchedRules.push(rules[j].cssText);
            }
        }
    }
    return matchedRules;
}
```

You can then call the function to obtain the matched rules. For example:

```js
getCss("a:hover");
```

Comment: Thank you. I have also checked this method, but stylesheets are not always written systematically, so finding a corresponding css by selector is sometimes difficult.

Comment: @Akira could you elaborate further on what you mean by "written systematically"? What exactly would the problem be?

Comment: Because I want to check its CSS from a javascript element object, I first have to convert the element object into CSS selector(this is a bit complicated as well) and then have to execute your function. Obviously there are many different ways of writing CSS selectors for a certain element, ex. "div>span>a,class" can be "div a,class", so finding CSS by its string text does not always match.